# What are the options for mounting 24×34 wedding-portrait prints?

Tags: prints

In about four months, I have a wedding shoot coming up. The couple has requested a 24x34 print. I usually order my 20x30’s on a Single & Double Weight Matboard, but I feel like the print itself can easily be scratched. Many local photographers print on a type of foam mount that has a water resistant print that feels like plastic when touched. It's something I might want to go for. What other options, pros and cons, should I be considering?

Comment: A mounted print is tougher to mat and frame. If they're planning on framing, using a matboard and then cardboard backing the whole thing will give plenty of support. So...what's the endgame?

Comment: Have you asked the couple about their preferences (mainly framed or not)?

Comment: Yes it will be framed, I’ve always gotten prints on mounts and then had them framed with no problem. I’ve only ever really used double weight matboard, never really used foam core or canvas on matboard. It all comes down to what type of print would be best to mount to have it last for years to come.

Comment: Those are really odd dimensions. Is there an existing frame/matte? Is 24x34 the size of the frame or of the inner dimensions of the matte? What thickness mount does the existing frame allow?

Comment: 24x34 are the dimensions of the print alone, the thickness of the matboard is about half an inch. The frame is not included in this but I’ve mounted them with no problem. I too thought it was odd since most people ask for 20x30’s

Comment: cm?  inches? ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is classy enough for a wedding photo but I've done for-hire prints on a [Plak-it](https://www.plak-it.com/) before and the client was thrilled with the results, particularly because they "hate frames."

Comment: How was the quality? Have you used Mpix? If so, how does it stand against it.

Comment: I can't say that I've used Mpix. The quality is not quite as good as what I can do with my Epson 4800 but it is better than what I've seen others do with their pro printers. I would say the key to getting a result which is both pleasing and what someone would call a photograph is to choose your finishing options carefully.